# CROSS JOIN only certain AND clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a situation where a CROSS JOIN is done within a query. I now want to add rows to this resultset, but these extra rows do not need to be crossjoined.

Example:

```
SELECT 1,2,3
FROM tbl
INNER JOIN   [abc].[def].[ghi]
ON 1=1 -- this is the cross join
WHERE ((A BETWEEN B AND C) OR (A IS NULL AND D IN (
                                                   SELECT D 
                                                   FROM #TMP_table
                                                  )
                               )
       )
```

Now, I only want the crossjoined resultset from the first part of the WHERE CLAUSE. The OR clause should just be added to the resultset and not be CROSS JOINED.

Is this possible or am I trying something impossible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you need `UNION ALL`. Add samples of data and an expected result.

Comment: `INNER JOIN ghi ON 1=1 -- this is the cross join` What???? Why not `CROSS JOIN ghi` then? And the `WHERE` clause doesn't contain any criteria comparing values of both tables? If it did, then this would not be a cross join, but an obfuscated inner join.

Comment: Anyway, your question is not clear. Follow Radim Bača's advice and show sample data and expected result to illustrate what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 1,2,3
FROM tbl
CROSS JOIN   [abc].[def].[ghi]
WHERE A BETWEEN B AND C

UNION ALL

SELECT 1,2,3
FROM tbl
INNER JOIN   [abc].[def].[ghi]
ON ...
WHERE A IS NULL AND D IN 
(
    SELECT D 
    FROM #TMP_table
)
```